# Why is there no "pathspec" when I try to remove a folder in Git?

Tags: git

I am trying to remove a folder from my Git repository with

```
git rm folderToRemove
```

but Git issues this error when I try to do so.

```
fatal: pathspec 'siteFiles/applicationFiles/templates/folderToRemove' 
did not match any files
```

My current directory is "templates." I am finding this error odd since I can `cd` into the folder "folderToRemove," so it clearly exists. What does this error mean?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Git doesn't version directories, only "content" (directory content or files)

> did not match any files

That means there is no file to remove within `folderToRemove`, as I mention in "[Unable to remove files recursively from Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1054933/6309)".
You now can remove (Windows `del` or Unix `rm`) the directory itself.

As described in "[Deleting empty directories in Git](http://geektastical.com/2011/03/deleting-empty-directories-in-git/)", you can also run a:

```
git clean -fd
```

However:

> Warning: The clean command removes any files in the current working copy that aren’t being tracked by git. This is a good way to lose your work if you haven’t added new files to git. Always run `git add` before `git clean`.

Run rather first a:

```
git clean -d -x -n
```

As explained in "[How do I clear my local working directory in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673407/how-do-i-clear-my-local-working-directory-in-git)".

Comment: but how do I "clean" another person's remote when they do a pull?

Comment: @IleaCristian due to the distributed nature of Git, you don't clean a remote, only your own clone.

Comment: The problem is that we don't make the final build. The project files (that the IDE sees) are actually some folders with "extension" (myproj.xcworkspace or myproj.xcodeproj). I wanted to remove the xcworkspace and leave only the xcodeproj. Basically I wanted to force the people that make the build to use only the xcodeproj file.